# How to configure custom security token handler?

Tags: wcf, security, configuration, token, identityserver3

I have implemented custom **Saml2SecurityTokenHandler** as shown here http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/02/give-your-wcf-security-architecture-a-makeover-with-identityserver3/.

The constructor of this handler accepts two custom parameters - authority and requiredScopes. In the example this handler is registered in the code. However, I want to do this in web.config file.

`<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <clear />
        <add type="MyNamespace.MyCustomSaml2SecurityTokenHandler, MyAssembly" />

      </securityTokenHandlers>

    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>`

Is it possible to pass somehow from the configuration (web.config), these two constructor parameters?

Answer (score 0):

give your class MyCustomSaml2SecurityTokenHandler a zero-parameter constructor.

Get those details at run time from your local config on the server side.